# Bind multipal value in grid

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try :

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Local ">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLocal"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LPName") == null ? "" : Eval(Title) %>' ></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

i want if field`LPName` have not any value, take value from `title`.But unable to do this.Is there any method or i am in wrong way.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double quote is missing with `Title` field,

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLocal"  runat="server" 
       Text='<%# Eval("LPName") == null ? "" : Eval("Title") %>'>
</asp:TextBox>
```